# Mersenne Primes using Mersenne Primes as n

Tags: prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

I have been exploring the fascinating world of prime numbers, particularly Mersenne Primes, and have noticed an interesting pattern.  It seems to me that $2^n - 1$ is prime as long as $n$ itself is a Mersenne prime.

I already know that $2^n - 1$ is not necessarily prime just because $n$ is a normal prime number, but I have not found a counterexample that to the claim that $2^n - 1$ is a prime whenever $n$ is a Mersenne prime.

Is there a proof that this claim is false?

Comment: True for the first four Mersenne primes, and false for the fifth one already - see [here](https://www.mersenne.org/primes/).

Comment: I know some facts don't related directly with your question. Maybe you know those, I cited these because I think that are important. You can see from this [*The Prime Page*, by   Professor Chris Caldwell](https://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/index.html) the graph for Mersenne primes in section 6 *Where is the next larger Mersenne prime?*. On the other hand I like very much also several conjectures due to Professor Farideh Firoozbakht, you can read these in [*The Prime Puzzles & Problems Connection*, by Carlos Rivera](http://www.primepuzzles.net/). I say for example the Puzzle 434 and Puzzle 517.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2^{13}-1 = 8191$ is a Mersenne prime, but $2^{8191}-1$ is composite.

Comment: Excellent, I knew that logically there had to be a counterexample, I just couldn't find one on the internet.  If there is an article that goes into depth on this, or where you got this example, please link to it!

Comment: @KernelStearns But this *is* on the internet; the above list says that $2^{8191}-1$ is *not* a (Mersenne) prime.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see now the small type at the bottom that implies every Mersenne prime between 0 and M37,156,667 is on the list.  However, this post was meant to provide a quick answer to other people who are new to primes and have the same question.

Comment: That's fine. I only wanted to argue about your statement "I just couldn't find one on the internet." Here the homepage on Mersenne "www.mersenne.org" immediately suggest itself.

Comment: In the past I tried to combine some problems as the mentioned in the top, Puzzle 434 and Puzzle 517 by Firoozbakht from The Prime Puzzles & Problems Connection, or Puzzle 774 by Noahiro Nomoto with the equation for integers $n>1$ involving the sum of remainders function (see the article [1] or [2]), but I didn't any remarkable deduction. Maybe you or @DietrichBurde can do experiments in your home about it. [1] T.  Cross, *A note on almost perfect numbers*, Mathematics Magazine, 47 (1974), 230–231. [2] Z. Spivey, *The Humble Sum of Remainders Function*, Mathematics Magazine, 78, No. 4 (2005).

Comment: also yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508390/can-you-prove-that-this-number-isnt-prime-the-number-is-22127-1-1